# "ReferenceError: prompt is not defined" in Atom

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I am new to JavaScript and editor Atom. I tired to write a code to prompt things in Atom, eg.

```
prompt("what's your name?");
```

But I got the following error message. Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you in advance.

```
ReferenceError: prompt is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (***/prmpthiwld.js:2:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
at startup (node.js:136:18)
at node.js:966:3
```

Comment: The error is because you are trying to use a browser extension to JS in NodeJS (presumably by hitting the Run This JS button in Atom). Where are you actually intending to run the finished JavaScript? Are you writing for NodeJS? For a web page? For an Atom Extension? You will either need to find an alternative to prompt or change the way you are testing your code.

Comment: I was just practising the js code in atom for web development, so its for web page. I did Shift + Ctrl + b to run the code, is it the same as what you mentioned, Run this JS button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most GUI toolkits, there is no native support for prompt. I think, contributors of Atom editor didn't want to deal with this problem.

There are non-blocking, non-native plugins to support prompt, alert etc.

https://github.com/coderaiser/smalltalk

https://github.com/jameskyburz/dialogs

You can use one of these.

Also you can see [discussion](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/472) about why prompt is not implemented.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tuğca